# Kendo UI Detailstemplate in Grid Fails Validation

Tags: validation, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using `Kendo UI` in my ASP.NET MVC 4.0 application.

I have a grid with detailed templates
in my details template i have a form

```
  @(Html.Kendo().TabStrip()
            .Name("TabStrip_#=UserID#")
            .SelectedIndex(0)
            .Events(e => e.ContentLoad("UserDetailsEditable"))
            .Items(tab =>
            {
                tab.Add().Text("User Details")
                    .LoadContentFrom("UserDetails", "User", new { UserID = "#= UserID #"});
            })
            .ToClientTemplate()
```

)

This form is not firing validation derived from Model Data annotation.

That because it is not recognizing my validation scripts

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

if I move this reference @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
from **layout.cshtml** to **Form view** validations will work
but my form post will be done multiple times.
because my script reference will be loaded multiple time for each details template.

How can i over come this problem?

**Solution**:

I have split jQuery Val bundle

```
  //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            //           "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            //           "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/unobtrusive").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

in my layout i gave only  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")`

in all my form views i gave  `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

that solved the problem.
Hope this can help others

Comment: Shouldn't you put your solution in an answer and mark it as the solution? Until you do that this will continue to be marked as "unanswered."

Comment: @jebar8 I was bit confused with Stack overflow terms of answering own question. Any way answered. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have split jQuery Val bundle

```
 //bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
            //           "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*",
            //           "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/unobtrusive").Include(
                       "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive*"));
```

in my layout i gave only `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/unobtrusive")`

in all my form views i gave `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")`

that solved the problem. Hope this can help others